# elsarticle vs newclude vs bibliography

Tags: debugging, elsarticle

Consider the MWE below. If we use `article` + `newclude` the bibliography works, `elsarticle` + `newclude` it does not.

My advise to the user to came by with this issue was not to use `newclude`, but now I'm curious, what is wrong?

```
% works with article + newclude
%\documentclass{article}
% does not work with elsarticle + newclude
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{newclude}
\begin{document}
\cite{t}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{t} Test
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I end up with in the `elsarticle` + `newclude` case:

[image]

Comment: Consider that `elsarticle` is from 2009, whereas `newclude` is from 1999 or 2000 and hasn't been updated so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elsarticle` loads `natbib`, which redefines `\@lbibitem`. But newclude resets it to the standard definition (in `tag.sto`). So this shows the same problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\makeatletter\show\@lbibitem

\usepackage[simple]{newclude}
%\makeatletter\show\@lbibitem

\begin{document}
\cite{t}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{t} Test
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Contrary to the claims in the documentation one can't suppress the loading of `tag.sto` with the option `simple`. (And the option `allocate` gives errors). So it has bugs. I wouldn't use this package.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. It was also my recommendation to not use `newclude`. The user used it to suppress the `\clearpage` but it seemed  the user did not know `\input` and especially not the difference between `\include` and `\input`. We removed `newclude` and switched to `\input` and it worked just fine.