# elsarticle.cls and multiple bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, elsarticle

I'm using a journal publisher's custom class for the preparation of a manuscript; `elsarticle.cls` which is often referenced on this forum (e.g. see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252109/elsarticle-vs-newclude-vs-bibliography?rq=1), as well as, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167426/bibliography-style-with-elsarticle?rq=1))

I understand that elsarticle uses bibtex.  I prefer to use biblatex with biber as a back-end.

My typical workflow involves calling one to five `.bib` databases which are typically associated with specific projects with an `\addbibresource` command.

Can anyone suggest a way to cite items from multiple bibliographies in a manuscript calling `elsarticle.cls` while still generating valid file outputs for submission to the publisher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to submit your paper to Elsevier (and this is the only good reason to use `elsarticle.cls`, I believe) you should follow their instructions as much as possible, use their template as-is and should definitely not modify it to use a package that is incompatible with the defaults loaded by the class (for `elsarticle` that would be `natbib`).

Publisher classes are usually meant to enable a simple and smooth workflow for the publisher. The workflow for citations and the bibliography with `biblatex` is significantly different from the workflow with BibTeX. For starters `biblatex` does not produce typesettable TeX code in a `thebibliography` environment. That means that publishers, whose workflow uses `\bibitem`/`thebibliography` as produced by BibTeX or used in manual bibliographies, will in all likeliness not be able to process submissions with `biblatex` bibliographies properly. See also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864).

It is possible to make `elsarticle` use `biblatex` (see [biblatex instead of natbib in elsarticle, how?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321989/35864)), but I'm almost certain that Elsevier won't like that (cf. for example [I cannot make my biblatex work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378656/35864)). If you need something in your paper that the provided template can't do and that can't be implemented in a compatible way, you should contact the editor and ask for further instructions.

Comment: well put and thank you for the interest.  I certainly agree.  At the risk of shifting the discussion off-topic, what about a solution which is just an easy / semi-automated way to build a single bibliography from multiple `.bib` databases?  This would be step in the writer's workflow that occurs before citing a new work.

Comment: @JohnChris It is already possible to take entries from several `.bib` files, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84099/35864. If the publisher wants to you to upload the `.bib` file and lets you upload several files that should work. If they want you to upload the `.bbl`, this is guaranteed to be OK. Of course you could also write a script to combine several `.bib`s into one larger `.bib`. But I'm not sure that is what you were thinking about.

Comment: You're right.  Seems this is a non-issue.  If I do, say, `\def\bibnamea{<database a>}%` and `\def\bibnameb{<database b>}%` in the preamble and my bibliography call looks like: `\bibliography{bibnamea,bibnameb}%` I can successfully reference citations from multiple databases using bibtex.  Note that the database file name is the full filepath excluding the `.bib` extension.