# Different colors for each bib file and custom prefix [Elsevier]

Tags: color, elsarticle, multibib

I have multiple bib files. I would like to use different text colors for all the references mentioned in different bib files. Secondly, I would like a custom prefix for each bib file.

Please let me know how can I do it?

The result should be similar to as follows:

> [R1] uses [O1] and [R2] is based on [O2].
>
> **References**
>
> [R1] .....
>
> [R2] .....
>
> **Other References**
>
> [O1] ....
>
> [O2] ....

The color of references mentioned in section "References" should be black, where as color of references mentioned in section "Other references" should be blue.

Any example should work with the `elsarticle` class such as

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint,10pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc}
```

Comment: I guess it would make sense to remove the `biblatex` tag since `elsarticle` is incompatible with `biblatex`. (For those interested: the `biblatex` answer to the question is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470852/35864)

Comment: That said: I see only one reason to use `elsarticle`, namely when you submit to an Elsevier journal. In that case it is unlikely that you will be able to use any of the (quite likely) tricky solutions that one might come up with to achieve what you want. As I wrote in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468152/35864, if a publisher class can't do what you want, ask the editor how to do it or don't do it at all. If, on the other hand, you don't plan to submit to Elsevier I would not use `elsarticle` at all.

Comment: Actually, I need to submit the paper to Elsevier journal, and for this purpose, I cannot avoid elsarticle. If there is any solution for the above mentioned problem which can also work with elsarticle, that will be great.

Comment: Firstly, not everything that is theoretically possible is a good idea when you want to submit a paper to a publisher. I suppose they have quite strict guidelines on their bibliographies and I doubt that they allow for split references with colours and such. Have you ever seen the scheme you have in mind in the journal you want to publish with? It is possible to change the entire text colour to red and the font to Comic Sans MS, but Elsevier will probably not like that. So even if it can be done chances are it goes against policy or style guides of your journal.

Comment: Secondly, it might be tricky to get exactly what you want within the limits that your document class imposes. `elsarticle` uses `natbib`, which is nice, but you would probably have to load `multibib` or a similar package and would have to hack quite a few commands. Those technicalities make it not only difficult to implement something, it also makes it less likely that the workflow on the Elsevier side will be compatible with what you have to conjure up.